# What are the conditions to be able to decompose a matrix A into the product of a matrix B with its conjugate transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the conditions on a matrix $A$ such that it can be written as $BB^{adj}$ for some matrix $B$? What is this property called?

Comment: If $A$ is Hermitian and positive-semidefinite (its eigenvalues are zero or positive), then there exists such a $B$. There exists a unique such $B$ if we insist that $B$ is also Hermitian and positive-semidefinite. Finally, $B B^\dagger$ is Hermitian and positive-semidefinite for any $B$, so this is a complete characterisation of the property.

Comment: Note that the notation $B^{\text{adj}}$ is rare. It is more common to denote the conjugate transpose by $B^*,B^\dagger,B'$ or $B^H$.